# In InDesign how can you script to detect a locked object?

Tags: adobe-indesign, layers, indesign-scripting, master-page, cc-2017

I have an InDesign brochure that I'm trying to script against however I'm running into issues.  When I try to script against the 100 page brochure I get an:

> Error Number: 11274; Error String: Object is locked

When I go through the three master page layers' there is no locked layer and when I land on a page the `Layer Panel` still shows no locked layer on the top and child level areas.  Thinking it might be a file issue I tried exporting the brochure to an IDML and opening again then saving as a new INDD but the issue still exists.

I've tried scripting:

```
app.activeDocument.pageItems.everyItem().locked = false;
```

on all the pages before tying to manipulate the zero text frame with (`app.select(allPages[x].textFrames[0]);`) through a for loop but the issue still occurs.  Thinking it might be a master page issue I've tried:

```
app.activeDocument.masterSpreads.everyItem().pageItems.everyItem().locked = false;
```

but I still get the same results.  When referencing the InDesign scripting documentation under [Working with Layers](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/sdk/cs6/scripting/InDesign_ScriptingGuide_JS.pdf) the selection regarding locking layers is limited.

How can I script through an InDesign document that is producing an object lock or is there a way I can isolate the locked object?

Comment: What's the code line in which the error occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
app.activeDocument.allPageItems.everyItem().locked = false;
```

http://yearbook.github.io/esdocs/#/InDesign/Document/allPageItems

Normally you need to access pageItems through their page. So your `app.activeDocument.pageItems...` leads nowhere.

Same thing is valid for the masterspreads. They have pages as sub collection. So your code for that should be:

```
app.activeDocument.masterSpreads.everyItem().pages.everyItem().pageItems.everyItem().locked = false;
```

Also I suggest trying to find it visually. This code will walk through all pages and make the locked items magenta. It will also print messages to the ESTK.

```
function main () {
  var doc = app.activeDocument;
  for(var i = 0; i < doc.pages.length; i++) {
    $.writeln('\'I\'m on page ' + i);
    var page = doc.pages[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < page.pageItems.length; j++) {
      var item = page.pageItems[j];
      if(item.locked === true) {
      // do something to the page item so you can
      // find it visually
        $.writeln('found a locked item');
        item.fillColor = doc.swatches[5]; // normally it is magenta
      }
    }
  }
}
main();
```